# Chromе does not recognize profiles

Tags: google-chrome

I have 4 profiles but since Chrome crashed in the profile manager it recognizes only the default (1st). Their folders are still in User Data. Is there a way I can be able to switch profiles again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the profile data is still there, but Chrome has forgotten them, I suggest
this procedure :

- Backup all folders
- Create a new profile
- Replace its data with that of one of the saved folders
- Check if everything has been returned
- If yes, repeat for the other folders.